# Use :before and :after pseudo classes to insert tags

Tags: css

Can I use pure CSS to insert HTML tags with the `:before` and `:after` pseudo classes. I am working with Gravity forms which creates the form in a `ul` list.

I essentially want to insert my own wrappers with CSS for styling purposes. Here is an example of what gravity forms puts out. I want to wrap `.foo` with a `div`

```
<ul class="gform">
  <li>...</li>
  <li class="foo">...</li>
</ul>
```

Idea for the CSS...

```
.foo:before {
  content: "<div class='wrapper'>";
}

.foo:after {
  content: "</div>";
}
```

Comment: No, whatever is generated by them does not belong to DOM

Comment: There was once a proposal for a pseudo element named [`::outside`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2003/WD-css3-content-20030514/#wrapping) which would have done what you want. It never made it though.